# Why does UUID.fromString() not throw IllegalArgumentException for this UUID?

Tags: java, uuid

I'm trying to validate that a string is a `UUID`.  Apparently I don't understand what a valid UUID is. This is what I thought was an invalid `UUID - 55bb6be3-078c-4a49-a4e6-1e05776ed7e81234`

But when I pass that to `UUID.fromString()`, instead of throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, it returns a uuid with the value `55bb6be3-078c-4a49-bee7-776ed7e81234`

Comment: While it matches `8-4-4-4-12`, it is a correct UUID

Comment: I guess that's the point - it is `8-4-4-4-16`.

Comment: I see. @user26270, you can validate UUID explained in this link [http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/uuid-simple-technique-for-uuid.html](http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/uuid-simple-technique-for-uuid.html)

Comment: thanks for that blog link, that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

To throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, there should be less than 4 dashes - or 5 components. Here is the code part that throws the exception:

```
 String[] components = name.split("-");
 if (components.length != 5)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid UUID string: "+name);
```

Your input is not invalid, it has overflew components, therefore the returning `UUID` is different from the input.